# How do i make the below syntax to work ( cells("$variable","Q"))?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

```
Sub omnama()
ActiveSheet.Range(Cells("$1", "$A"), Cells("$39930", "$Q"))._
RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```

This is the code to remove the duplicates I have seen and my question is,
I wanna give a variable rather Than a number

```
cells("$39930","$Q") should be replaced with the below code
cells("$variable"),"$Q"))  but gives the error Type mismatch -- run time error 13
```

How do I make it work?
If i say

```
cells($variable,"$Q") ' says that invalid character
```

So how do i put a variable Value for these above code. Please let me know.Thank you in advance

Comment: You mean cells(variable,"$Q") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
Sub omnama()

Dim intRow as integer

intRow = 39930

ActiveSheet.Range(Cells("$1", "$A"), Cells("$" & CStr(intRow), "$Q"))._
RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9), Header:=xlYes
End Sub
```